# readr read_fwf strange parsing error: embedded null

Tags: r, parsing, readr, read.fwf

I am trying to use `readr::read_fwf` to read-in a .txt file. I know all of the column widths but I receive this parsing error which I do not know how to resolve:

```
 fwf_widths <- c(12, 2, 6, ...) 
 fwf_names <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", ...)
 col_types <- c("ccc...")

 df <- read_fwf(file = file, fwf_widths(fwf_widths, fwf_names), 
                         col_types = col_types)
Warning: 1 parsing failure.
row         col expected        actual        file                                                                         

372722 description          embedded null     /path/to/my/file.txt
```

I've tried adding `trim_ws = T` which does not get rid of the error. I looked at the actual contents of `df[372722, ]` and it looks like `description` contains the correct contents. Can someone please help me interpret what  `embedded null` means and how I can potentially deal with this issue?

Comment: Difficult to debug the issue without a reproducible example. Can you include one ?

Comment: Thanks for your response! It's hard to create a reproducible example for a problem regarding the reading in of a fwf file. I think what I'm primarily struggling with is how to understand "embedded null" itself which doesn't feel like it necessitates a toy dataset. "embedded" implies that there is some hard-to-read aspect of the variable's encoding. The "null" makes me think that there might be some sort of white-space surrounding this variable that this parsing error cannot interpret. I am just looking for any documentation on the subject, something I can't seem to find. Thanks again

Comment: I had similar problems, ended up pre-processing the file (before `readr::` or `read.csv` or whatever) with either `tr` or `sed`, suggestions for both in https://superuser.com/a/287998.

Answer (score 0):

One of the bytes in your fwf is a zero-value byte, which is illegal in an R character string. If you just remove it you will destroy the alignment of the subsequent entries in the fwf, so you need to replace it. The following function will write a space character by default at any zero byte locations.

**Please back up your .fwf file before using this**.

```r
replace_null <- function(path_to_file, file_size = 10000000L, replace_with = ' ')
{
  file_data <- readBin(path_to_file, "raw", file_size)
  file_data[file_data == as.raw(0)] <- as.raw(as.numeric(charToRaw(replace_with)))
  writeBin(file_data, path_to_file)
}
```

Now you just need to do

```r
replace_null(file_path)
```

and then your own code should work. If it doesn't, your fwf must be corrupted.

Comment: Thank you for this response, this was really helpful although I'm still experiencing this issue. If I'm having the same problem in a csv is there any problem with just removing the zero-value byte?

Comment: No, unless the file is corrupted and the null value is overwriting a comma you should be fine.